# Is this proof of the irrationality of $\sqrt{3}$ using only the definition of an even number valid?

Tags: solution-verification

Suppose for the sake of contradiction that $\sqrt{3}$ is rational.  Then $\sqrt{3} = p/q$ for $p,q \in \mathbb{Z}$.  Also assume that $p$ and $q$ have no common divisor, thus $p$ and $q$ can't both be even.

So, $\sqrt{3} = p/q \implies 3 = p^2/q^2 \implies p^2 = 3q^2 \implies 2p^2 = 6q^2 \implies 2p^2 = 2(3q^2).$

Since $2p^2$ is even, it follows that $p$ is even.  Thus, $p=2k$ for some $k\in \mathbb{Z}$.

So we have $2p^2 = 2(3q^2) \implies 2(2k)^2 = 2(3q^2) \implies 8k^2 = 6q^2 \implies 2(4k^2) = 6q^2.$

Since $6q^2$ is even, it follows that $q$ is even.  But $p$ and $q$ can't both be even, thus we have a contradiction.

Comment: Nope, $2(3^2)=18$ is even which does not imply that $3^2=9$ is even.

Comment: "Since $2p^2$ is even, it follows that $p$ is even" and "Since $6q^2$ is even, it follows that $q$ is even" are both seriously wrong.  If $p$ is an odd integer then $2p^2$ and $6p^2$ must be even

Comment: Your argument seems to work just as well to prove that $\sqrt 9$ is irrational.

Comment: Henry, if $p$ is an even integer then $2p^2$ and $6p^2$ must also be even right?

Comment: $2\cdot 3^2$ is even but $3$ isn't even.

Comment: In the proof that $\sqrt 2$ is irrational, you get that $2p^2=q^2,$ and you deduce first that $q$ is even (because $q^2$ is even.) From that, you conclude that $p$ is even. You can't conclude that $p$ is even just because $2p^2$ is even - indeed $2p^2$ is always an integer when $p$ is any integer.

Comment: If we had $p^2=2(3q^2)$ we say $p^2$ is even by the definition of an even number which is $2k$ for some $k\in\mathbb{Z}$.  So we have $p^2=2k$ for $k=3q^2$.  Thus if $p^2$ is even, $p$ must be even.  So if this is true, then $2p^2$ must be even.

Comment: Really, go through your argument using $\sqrt 9$ instead of $\sqrt 3$. Almost nothing changes.  You get $p^2=9q^2$ which you can multiply by $2$ to get $2p^2=18q^2$ so $2p^2$ is even which, according to you at least, somehow implies that $p$ is even, and so on.  But of course $\sqrt 9$ *is* rational.

Comment: Thanks, I know I'm wrong, just trying to pinpoint it.  Will need to reflect on this.

Comment: Never use "solution verification" as the *only tag for your question*.